# How to prove this is an harmonic function?

Tags: harmonic-functions, scalar-fields

I need some help with the following:

If $f$ and $g$ are two harmonic functions in $R^2$, i.e., $\Delta f = 0$ and $\Delta g = 0$. Can we say that the scalar function $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g$ is harmonic too, i.e., $\Delta (\nabla f \cdot \nabla g) = 0$? I have the feeling that some properties of the mixed partial derivatives are needed. Thanks in advanse.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:: Let $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=xy$.

Answer (score 2):

We have the easy-to-prove identity
$$ \Delta(fg) = g\Delta f + 2\nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f\Delta g, $$
and applying another Laplacian to this gives
$$ \Delta\Delta(fg) = \Delta(g\Delta f + 2\nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f\Delta g ) = 2\Delta(\nabla f \cdot \nabla g ). $$
Therefore for harmonic $f$ and $g$, $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g$ is harmonic if and only if $fg$ is biharmonic.